# userEvent not firing on table row

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a table component where I add an `onClick` handler to all `tr`s. The click handler works fine n the browser.
When it comes to write a test using testing library I can only get it work by using `fireEvent`. When I try to replace this with `userEvent` the click handler is not called. I'm aware that adding click handler to `tr`s has some issues with accessibility, but I would like to understand why its not triggered using `userEvent`

```js
render( <Table />)
const row = screen.queryAllByTitle('Show details')[0]
userEvent.click(row)
expect(screen.queryByText('Details')).toBeTruthy()
```

and the row:

```js
<tr
  title="Show details"
  onClick={showDetails}
  role="button"
>
  <td>....
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userEvent` is async. You can make the following changes if you want to use `userEvent`

```js
test('test row onClick', async () => {
  render( <Table />)
  const row = screen.queryAllByTitle('Show details')[0]
  await userEvent.click(row)
  expect(screen.queryByText('Details')).toBeTruthy()
})
```